# Java: System devices

Tags: java

How do I get all the system devices in a list of Files or Strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the static method: File.listRoots();

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to identify all of the Unix/Linux device "files" in a list of Files, then I think the answer is that you can't.

The `File.isFile()` and `File.isDirectory()` methods can tell you if a `File` is a regular file or a directory.  If you use `File.getCanonicalFile()` you can distinguish symbolic links.

But this still leaves character device files, block devices files, FIFOs (named pipes) and Unix domain sockets.  AFAIK, you cannot distinguish these cases using pure Java.